# Spring boot , i18n error, wrong implementation of LocaleResolver is choosen

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a spring boot based application that supports internationalisation

My env:

- Jdk11
- Spring boot 2.7.0
- Spring Security

Here is my web mvc conf

WebMvcConf.java

```java
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
    
    import java.util.Locale;
    
    @Configuration
    public class WebMvcConf  implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        public static final Locale idnLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("id-ID");
    
        @Bean
        public LocaleResolver defaultLocaleResolver(){
            var resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
            resolver.setDefaultLocale(idnLocale);
            return resolver;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
            var interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
            interceptor.setIgnoreInvalidLocale(false);
            interceptor.setParamName("lang");
    
            return interceptor;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        }
    }
```

And here is my security config:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConf{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()//enable cors
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()//disable csrf
                .sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))//stateless session (Rest)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz->authz
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users/login","users/register","users/forgot-password").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/users/password").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());//authorize any request except ignored endpoint above
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

}
```

Here is the structure of the message properties:
[image]

Here is my application.yml content:
[image]

Here is the content of messages_en.properties:

```
rest.welcome.ok=Welcome to ABC Backend Service, have fun!!!
rest.users.login.ok=Successfully Logged in

#Error Message
rest.500.err=Internal Server Error
rest.422.err=Constraint Violation Error
rest.400.err=Invalid request body
rest.required-req-body-missing.err=Required request body is missing
```

Here is content of messages.properties:

```
rest.welcome.ok=Selamat Datang di Service ABC, selamat bersenang-senang!!!
rest.users.login.ok=Login sukses


#Error message
rest.500.err=Kesalahan Internal di sistem
rest.422.err=Error pelanggaran constraint
rest.400.err=Kesalahan pada request body
rest.required-req-body-missing.err=Request body (payload) yang dibutuhkan tidak ditemukan
```

Here is my test to test the message source:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;

import java.util.Locale;

@SpringBootTest
public class MessageSourceTest {



    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    @BeforeEach
    void init(){
    }
    @Test
    public void message_provided_should_correctly_localized(){
        String msgEnglish = messageSource.getMessage("rest.500.err",null, new Locale("en"));
        String msgIndo = messageSource.getMessage("rest.500.err",null,Locale.forLanguageTag("id-ID"));
        Assertions.assertEquals("Internal Server Error",msgEnglish);
        Assertions.assertEquals("Kesalahan Internal di sistem",msgIndo);
    }
}
```

And the test is pass:
[image]

But when I try to hit a mvc rest controller and add query parameter `lang=en` , I always got an error response saying `Cannot change HTTP accept header - use a different locale resolution strategy`

So I debug the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` and found that spring boot provide a wrong implementation of the `LocaleResolver`, they provide `AcceptHeaderResolver`, which what I want is the `SessionLocaleResolver` as I state it in my `WebMvcConf` class. See following picture:
[image]

Anyone knows what is wrong and how to fix it?any response will be appreciated

Comment: The wrong one isn't chosen, you used the wrong configuration. The name of the bean for the `LocaleResolver` **must be** `localeResolver` yours is `defaultLocaleResolver` and as such doesn't match and thus the Spring Boot default is used.  To fix rename your method.